# Projection operator (redundant?) definition

Tags: linear-algebra, projection-matrices, self-adjoint-operators

In his *Quantum Mechanics*, Ballentine says that “in general, a self-adjoint operator which obeys $\rho^2=\rho$ is a projection operator”. I'm not sure I follow the need for the self-adjoint caveat? I thought that $\rho^2=\rho$ *defined* a projection operator? Is there any reason he would add this caveat that I'm missing, perhaps in the application to the weird (rigged Hilbert) spaces in which quantum mechanics is done?

Comment: Self-adjoint gives an orthogonal projection.

Comment: In QM, I think all the operators you deal with are self-adjoint (that's what Wikipedia seems to indicate). So I don't know if they are just emphasizing that, or what. There definitely exist non-self adjoint projections on Hilbert spaces, but I would have expected them to quite early on say "unless explicitly noted, all operators will be assumed to be self adjoint".

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Prof. Shifrin. Are there any major theorems of note which follow for orthogonal projections but not for oblique projections? I simply can't think of when this would make a difference, though as pointed out in the other comment, most operators of import in QM are self-adjoint. @TedShifrin

Comment: Just various orthogonality relations (e.g., between the kernel and the image).

Comment: Noted, thank you! @TedShifrin